# Need help displaying 3D video in flash, using NVIDIA 3D Vision

Tags: actionscript-3, video, air

I am trying to integrate 3D video into Adobe air. HALP!!!

I see that youtube has 3D videos 
http://www.3dvisionlive.com/content/smart-kid-teaser-3d

and displaying them with a flash player. Is there any documentation on this? I can't seem to find any.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you mean.
There's plenty of docs on html 5 and silverlight implementations, but no flash.
Perhaps youtube bought exclusive rights to the flash player?

Comment: This is a programming question. Thanks for the link but it's not what I'm looking for.

I'm looking for examples of how to integrate 3D video using 3D vision in Air.

Comment: my bad. I read your question as 'how do i get 3d videos on youtube'. You want to implement something similar to what youtube has?

Comment: I'm trying to play 3D Video but not sure where to begin. I'm currently looking at some workarounds but the optimal solution is to do it within Air.

Comment: there different ways to create the 3d effect. to do it right and have it be convincing, you need to start with stereoscopic video. You can either record your video with two cameras at the same time, or use some fancy video editing software to generate a best guess for what the two different eyeball viewpoints would look like. That's what your nvidia software does, and it looks like youtube does it for you as well. Once you have the video with two video channels for the different eyeball perspectives, you can create a player which displays the red channel from one, and the blue from the other.